# Entity Framework Core using Include not serializing to JSON correctly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have these 3 tables I am querying.

[image]

This is the query I am using.

```
                               return _db.ParticipantSkill.Where(x => x.ParticipantID == id && x.CreatedDate >= fromDate && x.CreatedDate <= toDate)
                .Include(x => x.AssessmentArea.ParticipantAssessmentArea).Where(c => c.CreatedDate >= fromDate && c.CreatedDate <= toDate)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
select * from ParticipantSkill join AssessmentArea on AssessmentArea.AssessmentAreaID = ParticipantSkill.AssessmentAreaID join ParticipantAssessmentArea on ParticipantAssessmentArea.AssessmentAreaID = AssessmentArea.AssessmentAreaID where ParticipantSkill.ParticipantID = 1 and ParticipantSkill.CreatedDate >= '11/17/2016' and ParticipantSkill.CreatedDate <= '11/17/2016' and ParticipantAssessmentArea.CreatedDate >= '11/17/2016' and ParticipantAssessmentArea.CreatedDate <= '11/17/2016'
```

Controller action

```
        public IActionResult GetParticipantSkills(int id, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)//todo pass dates
    {
        var skills = _repo.GetParticipantSkillsByParticipantIDAndDate(id, fromDate, toDate);
        return Json(skills);
    }
```

JSON USING LINQ include gives me ParticipantAssessmentArea but only 1 object in the array

```
[{"participantSkillID":1424,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-17T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test1","participantID":1,"planOfAction":1,"rating":1,"skillID":1,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[],"assessmentArea":{"assessmentAreaID":1,"assessmentCode":"1.000","description":"Personal Information","functionalLimitationID":1,"functionalLimitation":null,"participantAssessmentArea":[{"participantAssessmentAreaID":4,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-13T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test","participantID":1,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[]}]}}]
```

JSON when WITHOUT the LINQ include in the gives me 4 objects in the array

```
[{"participantSkillID":1424,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-17T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test1","participantID":1,"planOfAction":1,"rating":1,"skillID":1,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[],"assessmentArea":null,"participant":null,"skill":null},{"participantSkillID":1425,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-17T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test2","participantID":1,"planOfAction":2,"rating":2,"skillID":2,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[],"assessmentArea":null,"participant":null,"skill":null},{"participantSkillID":1426,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-17T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test3","participantID":1,"planOfAction":3,"rating":3,"skillID":3,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[],"assessmentArea":null,"participant":null,"skill":null},{"participantSkillID":1427,"assessmentAreaID":1,"createdDate":"2016-11-17T00:00:00","finalizedDate":null,"notes":"test4","participantID":1,"planOfAction":1,"rating":1,"skillID":6,"participantAssessmentReport":[],"participantPIP":[],"assessmentArea":null,"participant":null,"skill":null}]
```

Why does adding the related entity return only the first record with its child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the JsonSerializerSettings like this to allow the references to be serialized.

```
            return Json(skills, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
        });
```